# How to dynamically add DefinitionSeries to a StackedAreaChart in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, stacked-area-chart

I want to code sth where I can dynamically add a new random-value-series to a Silverlight StackedAreaChart. That is, everytime the user clicks a button at runtime I want a new value series in a different color added to the programs main StackedAreaChart.

I cannot find any good examples of this on the internet except for the [Silverlight Visualization demos (Stacked Area example)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/22/nobody-likes-a-show-off-today-s-datavisualizationdemos-release-includes-new-demos-showing-off-stacked-series-behavior.aspx).

The programmer made it static with three predefined series, but i want it to be dynamic and cant figure it out :-/

I spent 2 weeks on this now, any help will be greatly appreciated since I'm new to this stuff :(

Thx ppl! :)

Comment: You want to add an item to the legend? Ok, I know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found time to create an example of dynamic random series.

XAML code is simple: one button and the chart.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Add random series" Click="AddSeries_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <chart:Chart x:Name="chart" Grid.Row="1">
        <chart:StackedAreaSeries />
    </chart:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind looks rather complex, but majority of code is used to generate random data. The main code is in the `AddSeries_Click` method.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private string[] categories = new[] { "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Lemons" };
    private Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    private int lastSeriesYear = 2011;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class ChartItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }

    private void AddSeries_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sd = new SeriesDefinition();
        sd.ItemsSource = categories.Select(c => new ChartItem { Title = c, Value = random.Next(30, 35) }).ToList();
        sd.Title = (lastSeriesYear--).ToString();
        sd.IndependentValuePath = "Title";
        sd.DependentValuePath = "Value";

        ((StackedAreaSeries)this.chart.Series[0]).SeriesDefinitions.Add(sd);
    }
}
```

If you rather like to work with view models and observable collections than with code-behind, I have the [extended chart class](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/silverlight-chart-multiple-series-databinding/) which allows data binding to a list of series. But it requires much more code, so let there be this example with code-behind.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great start, the problem I'm facing is it has to be a *stacked* area chart. i cannot figure out how to define the data structures to hold the values dynamically. Any help yould be greatly appreciated. Thx a lot!

Comment: @user751344 There is not so much to change. I've edited my answer, now I use StackedAreaSeries instead of AreaSeries.